# Effects of removing constraints programmatically xcode

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I'm making an animated interface in iOS with storyboard. I have a subclass of `UIView` called `AnimatedView` with all of the interface elements as its subviews.

I need to be able to change the frame, transform, bounds, alpha etc. of all these subviews. This is turning out to be a problem. When my `AnimatedView`'s `layoutSubviews` method is called by its parent, it calls some `UIView` private method called `_is_layout`, which changes all of my subviews' `bound` and `frame` properties back to what they used to be.

If I add the UIViews programmatically this doesn't happen and everything works fine, but I'm working with graphic designers and I don't want them to have to mess with code.

After some trial and error, I've found that removing all the Auto Layout constraints on `AnimatedView` keeps it from resetting the `frame`s, but it still resets the `bound`s. Here's what `AnimatedView`'s overridden `layoutSubviews` method looks like:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [self createAnimationsFromPlist: filePath];
    [self removeConstraints: self.constraints];
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //set everything to its initial frame
    [self.animator animate:0];
}
```

Am I on the right track by removing the constraints? I've read the [auto layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) and I can't figure out why this would help me. I'm not using constraints in the storyboard with `AnimatedView`, but `self.constraints` has 20 elements for some reason.

If it helps, here's an example of how I'm animating the views:

```
    - (void)animateFrame:(NSInteger)time
{
    float angle = angleFrames[time];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `frame`, `center`, or `bounds` properties directly when using Auto Layout, and transforms may not work as expected.

So yes, for this kind of animation, it is best to take the view out of control of Auto Layout.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a more complete or better way to take this view out of control of Auto Layout? Or does "removeConstraints" do it? I don't want to disable auto layout for the entire application since  I use it for some of the other view elements, but could that be my best bet?

Comment: If it's loaded from a nib, you could disable Auto Layout on that nib only, OR you could position it with placeholder constraints, then set `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints` to true and set its `autoresizingMask` appropriately.

Comment: I got it to work! I set the AnimatedView and all it's subviews' translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints to YES. This was a major headache until you helped me out, thanks for your help Austin!